# Append data to pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I need to format a pandas data frame to the following data look

The problem I can't formulate the data as shown in the following string, and I get a lot of errors and exceptions.

My main problem which I can not figure out, how to append for example from ID 1, a value, and for id 1, another value, in pandas dataframe, that is sorted

```
 s = """
     ,trajectory_id,x ,y ,frame
    0,1            ,0 ,-2,0
    1,1            ,0 ,-1,1
    2,1            ,0 ,0 ,2
    3,1            ,0 ,1 ,3
    4,2            ,2 ,2 ,4
    5,2            ,1 ,1 ,5
    6,2            ,0 ,0 ,6
    7,2            ,-1,-1,7
    """
```

X, Y are listed for an object ID, frame is an incremental variable

EACH FRAME I'm detecting and getting Object new coordinates with it's tracking ID

```
dic_car_lists = defaultdict(list)

trk = trk.astype(np.int32) ## trck is TRAJECTORY_ID



 p = np.array([[((trk[1] + trk[3]) / 2,  (trk[0] + trk[2]) / 2)]], dtype=np.float32)
            center_pt = cv2.perspectiveTransform(p, H)

            point_lists[trk[4]].append(center_pt.T)
            x = [i[0] for i in point_lists[trk[4]]]
            y = [i[1] for i in point_lists[trk[4]]]
            x = list(map(lambda dd: float(dd[0]),x))
            y = list(map(lambda dd: float(dd[0]),y))
            dic_car_lists[trk[4]].append([trk[4], x, y, frame_idx])


def compute(data,df_region, df_line):
        gb = ('trajectory_id',)
        card_data = np.array(data)
        columns = ['trajectory_id', 'x_world', 'y_world', 'frame']

        car_d[card_data[0]].append(data)
        df = pd.DataFrame(list(car_d.items()),
                     columns=columns)

       compute( dic_car_list[trk[4]], df_region, df_line )
```

Comment: `append for example from ID 1, a value, and for id 1, another value`, what? Please can you better explain what you're trying to do

Comment: please give a clear example of the data input and what data output you want to obtain. Format correctly your code, and explain what is wrong with the code you have now, otherwise it is difficult to help you.

Comment: @yatu as you see in the sample string, ID 1 has X,Y, and then ID1 has another different X,Y. So I want to append each frame trajectory ID, with it's X,Y value in panadas dataframe